# Get depth of each pixels in image (Gray scale) by python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, depth

How I can get a depth of each pixel in a gray image and compute the height (Z) as shown in the figure by using python , I use the following code to save image as matrix :

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
imageFile = 'D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\pic (17) - Copy.png'
mat = imread(imageFile)
mat = mat[:,:,0] # get the first channel
```

the value of Z in the mat always starts from 0 to 1, there is any formal to compute the real depth (Z)?

[Figure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DOdd.png)

Comment: Please put back the `import` statements! Otherwise we don't know whether you are using `imread()` from **OpenCV**, or **skimage** or something else. You also don't show your image. It's also unclear what *"depth"* you are trying to find... do you mean the bits per pixel, or some Kinect-type distance or something else?

Comment: I used matplotlib "from matplotlib.pyplot import imread" ..i mean distance as shown in the link in my question